# Can my team use a Chrome extension we developed without buying it? How? Where do I define the list of people that can use it?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We developed and published an extension that requires one time payment. How can I define a list of people from my organization that will be able to use it without paying?

Comment: Have you tried adding them as testers in the [Developer's dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't do that. But what you can do is make another version of the extension an publish it as a private chrome app, and then you choose your team users. [Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en) is a full article about this